# 1 bug to kill... Letting PHP Generate The Canonical

Tags: php, html, url, uri, canonical-link

for building a clean canonical url, that always returns 1 base URL, im stuck in following case:

```
<?php
# every page
$extensions = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  # path like: /en/home.ast?ln=ja
$qsIndex = strpos($extensions, '?');    # removes the ?ln=de part
$pageclean = $qsIndex !== FALSE ? substr($extensions, 0, $qsIndex) : $extensions;
$canonical = "http://website.com" . $pageclean;   # basic canonical url
?>

<html><head><link rel="canonical" href="<?=$canonical?>"></head>
```

when URL : `http://website.com/de/home.ext?ln=de`
canonical:  `http://website.com/de/home.ext`

**BUT** I want to remove the file extension aswell, whether its .php, .ext .inc or whatever two or three char extension `.[xx]` or `.[xxx]` so the base url becomes: `http://website.com/en/home`

Aaah much nicer! but How do i achieve that in current code?
Any hints are much appreciated +!

Comment: Does the `website.com/en/home` really resolve to the actual page?

Comment: Please note that what you're doing may end up causing issues on web-servers where resource addresses are not organized in this traditional way. Doubly so for what @chelmertz has pointed out, where the extension may be reuqired for resolving an address. What you're doing, I would have low-confidence for it working with external links.

Comment: @Chelmertz @ user257493  i'm not sure what you mean or how to test wether it works, other than when i type in URL of browser `website.com/ja/fruit` then it redirect to `http://website.com/ja/fruit` which brings page fruit, in japanese. What is wrong in this fashion? very curious. Please make your statement stronger with clearer argumentation with a `what will go wrong example` Thanks in advance for your concerns which is equally my concern.

Comment: @Sam, this isn't a debate or even remotely an argument, it's a simple fact. Different web servers have different resource address configurations. Just because the server you're using is set up this way doesn't mean it works everywhere. Go figure out how web servers work.

Comment: @Sam by default address.com/bla most often resolves to address.com/bla/index.ext and not address.com/bla.ext hence my concern. If you're not affected, the answer would be 'yes' to my question :)

Comment: @user257493, i only use 1 webserver. Given this condition, can you please tell which `check` or `test` i can run to see that my server is configured wrongly, or how to find out the fact you are referring to applies to my situation, and sothat i have reason to be concerned. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this should do it, just strip off the end if there is an extension, just like you did for the query string:

```
$pageclean = $qsIndex !== FALSE ? substr($extensions, 0, $qsIndex) : $extensions;
$dotIndex = strrpos($pageclean, '.');
$pagecleanNoExt = $dotIndex !== FALSE ? substr($pageclean, 0, $dotIndex) : $pageclean; 
$canonical = "http://website.com" . $pagecleanNoExt;   # basic canonical url
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry! I seems this implementation gives empty result, leaving only the "http://website.com" and the $pagecleanNoExt is clean/empty!

Comment: I got the same empy-url as when trying the other answer. Seems im doing something wrong... if I only knew what...

Comment: There was 1 dollar sign `$` missing! `$dotIndex` seems seems working... testing

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
preg_match("/(.*)\.([^\?]{2,3})(\?(.*)){0,1}$/msiU", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $res);
$canonical = "http://website.com" . $res[1];
```

and $res[1] => clean url;
$res[2] = extension;
$res[4] = everything after the "?" (if present and if you need it)

Comment: thanks Ass3mbler, will give it a try. very different look into the matter. I would prefer php but will check this out and report back!

Comment: @Sam no problem, if it doesn't suit your needs or if you need more help just ask me here!

Comment: `preg_match("/(.*)\.([^\?]{2,3})(\?(.*)){0,1}$/msiU", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $res); $canonical = "http://website.com" . $res[1] . $res[2] . $res[3] . $res[4];`

outputs: `<link rel="canonical" href="http://website.com">`
So no good luck today...

Comment: could you write here the value of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] you are testing against the regexp?

Comment: Thanks very much Ass3mbler, somehow the preg_match doesnt work flawlessly but might have something to do with my server.. Anyways thanks very much for your post as this shows that there are `always many paths that take you to Rome`.